Does Windows 10 hibernation require the swap file to be on the system partition?
Hibernation works fine on my Windows 10 laptop, if pagefile.sys is on the system partition.  If I instead move it to a dedicated partition, the laptop hangs during resuming with the Windows logo on the screen; the spinner under it never shows up.
I have two SSDs and an NVMe in my laptop.  My system partition is mirrored between the SSDs.  I just added the NVMe.  My intent was to use the NVMe as a dedicated swap drive.  Unfortunately, resume no longer works.  I tested creating dedicated partitions on the SSDs for the swap file and resume doesn't work with it there either.  Resume works fine once I moved it back to the system partition.
I have fast startup disabled, and I tried disabling and reenabling hibernate.
Is this a Windows limitation or am I running into some other problem?

There is technically no restriction to having your pagefile on another drive than the OS drive. It's doubtful you will see noticeable performance difference between the SATA or NVMe SSD. So yes, you are running into another problem (slow wake on PCIe ?)

I was worried about the NVMe not being ready in time, that is why I tried it on the SSD as well.  Strange it can access the mirrored partition but not a normal one on the same SSD.

My issue is performance, not size.  Windows 10 does not support trim on mirrored partitions, so write performance is atrocious.  I only have 16GB of ram.  My system partition turned into a bottleneck.  I regularly had pauses of 5-10 seconds while the partition caught up.  Moving the page file to the NVMe fixed that problem.

It is indeed weird windows behaviour. But again, according to microsoft there shouldnt be an issue with maintaining swap files on none OS drives/partitions. Do you reboot after swapping pagefile location before trying hibernate ?

Yes, I rebooted after every configuration change.
